# Accessing array of variables in CakePHP bake script?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-bake

I'm trying to modify the CakePHP bake script so that I can incorporate saving of images from an image helper in an appropriately named field.

How do I go about getting the list of fields/variables in my model?  I see that the $modelObj object is available, I've tried performing json_encode on this to get an idea for what's inside and theres a "_schema" list which seems to have all my field names inside... but I can't access this as it's not an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a call to:

```
$this->ModelName->schema()
```

It will return a field-by-field list containing field names and data types.